# Why are JUnit 5 suite dependencies breaking my test classes?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit5

I am new to JUnit testing and have run into an issue that seems to be caused when I add the junit-platform-suite and junit-platform-suite-engine dependencies to my build file (pom.xml).

I am trying to create a test suite; however, when I add these dependencies, I am no longer able to run my test cases or test classes and the IDE returns that "No tests were found".

Below is my pom.xml file with the JUnit suite dependencies commented out. If I add one or both dependencies, my test cases/classes no longer work.

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-params -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-suite -->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.9.3</version>-->
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-suite-engine -->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.9.3</version>-->
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
```

I have tried to invalidate caches and reload, rebuild the module/project, clearing the config settings for JUnit, made sure the Sources Root and Test Sources Root were marked on the correct directory, etc. but nothing seems to work.

Comment: so why do you want to add them?

Comment: I am trying to create a test suite using JUnit 5 but I can't even get to that point because these dependencies are messing up my test classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

To simply run tests written with JUnit 5, you do *not* need the *…Suite…* tools. Just specify the [aggregate JUnit + Jupiter archetype](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter).

```xml
<artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
```

If you want to use the Suite features of JUnit, you need to add two more dependencies. Of course, you need at least one test engine such as *Jupiter*.

## Details

The [*JUnit Platform Suite Engine*](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#junit-platform-suite-engine) is for running tests with *any* of many possible [test engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#Java), and no one engine in particular.

### *Jupiter*

[JUnit 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit) is designed to be a harness for one or more test engines.

One test engine is provided by the JUnit team, named *Jupiter*. JUnit 5 can run Jupiter-based tests, and JUnit 5 can run tests from other third-party test engines. Jupiter is but one of several test engines compatible with JUnit 5.

If you just want to run Jupiter tests, the replacement for JUnit 4 tests, you do not need *JUnit Platform Suite Engine*. Instead, just configure your Maven POM to specify the [aggregate JUnit + Jupiter archetype](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter).

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.0-RC2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

That archetype brings in three artifacts:

- [JUnit Jupiter Engine](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine)
- [JUnit Jupiter API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api)
- [JUnit Jupiter Params](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-params)

These in turn bring in artifacts for the JUnit 5 test harness platform.

Here is an example [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model), my modified version of the POM from the [*Maven Quickstart Archetype*](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExJunitJupiter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>ExJunitJupiter</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>20</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0-RC2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.11.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.0-M3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

### Example test

Here is an example test, modified code taken from the [*Maven Quickstart Archetype*](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/).

```java
package work.basil.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest
{
    /**
     * Rigorous Test :-)
     */
    @Test
    public void shouldAnswerWithTrue ( )
    {
        assertTrue ( true );
    }
}
```

### Suite features

If you want to use the *Suite* features of JUnit 5, you need to add two more dependencies.

```java
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-suite-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0-RC2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-suite-engine -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0-RC2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

These resolve the imports in code such as my modified version of this example taken from the JUnit 5 documentation.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeClassNamePatterns;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SuiteDisplayName;

@Suite
@SuiteDisplayName ( "JUnit Platform Suite Demo" )
@SelectPackages ( "example" )
@IncludeClassNamePatterns ( ".*Tests" )
class SuiteDemo
{
}
```

See [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#junit-platform-suite-engine).

Comment: Thank you! I added the dependency that you mentioned in your response and removed all other dependencies except for 'junit-platform-suite' and now everything works.

Comment: If using only the 'junit-jupiter' dependency, what would be the class import for the test suite annotations (i.e., '@Suite', '@SelectClasses', etc.)?

Comment: @Mariko-chan See my edits for `junit-platform-suite-api` and `junit-platform-suite-engine`.

Answer (score 0):

you should ***not*** need

- junit-platform-suite
- junit-platform-suite-engine

with an up to date IDE, you should only need the junit-jupiter-* dependencies, but if you have an unusually or out of date IDE, you MAY need additional dependencies

see docs regarding what dependencies you *actually* need for your IDE
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide

pro tip: try running your Maven build with the tests from command line rather than from the IDE -- that will give you some indication of whether this is an IDE issue or an actual project dependency issue.